# Strange malloc issue

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to malloc a float ** that will be accessed like `arrayToFill[channel][frame] = 0.f;` but I am only able to access it if I do the following code piece, otherwise I get a bad access error.

```
arrayToFill = (float **) malloc((frameCount * 2) * sizeof(float *));

for(int i = 0; i < channelCount; i++)
{
    arrayToFill[i] = (float *) malloc(frameCount * sizeof(float));
}
```

This just seems completely incorrect.

Comment: What did you think would work? (Just FWIW, this looks correct to me).

Comment: What "seems incorrect" about it?

Comment: fwiw, you don't need to cast the return value of malloc in C, and judging from the various threads I've seen, people on SO feel that it shouldn't be done at all.

Comment: Ok, all of a sudden it looked completely strange to me. And If I recall this code a number(currently inconsistent) of times it crashes when the frameCount changes.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Not just the people here, you really, really shouldn't ever cast the return value of malloc in C.  It's not an opinion; it can hide problems and, at best, is redundant.  I have just given up repeating it.

Comment: I will remove that thanks. I have however seen this used in a number of audio related open source code

Comment: @Helium3 In older versions of C, you actually did have to cast the return value; it could be that the code dates from before the change was made.

Comment: It's "completely" incorrect if you count storing a different number of elements than you allocate to be completely incorrect. I find it baffling that such errors don't leap out at people.

Comment: @JimBalter: It was an attempt to prod the OP into being more descriptive.

Comment: @Ed S. The OP wrote "completely incorrect", not you .. I was referring to OP's comment, not yours. As for "keep it positive", I have no idea what that's about ... I can't look at that code without seeing the obvious error, and I would truly like to understand why others do ... software quality is an important issue, and it behooves us to understand all aspects of why there is so much bad software. It certainly wasn't a personal criticism.

Answer (score 4):

This seems should be like:

```
float **arrayToFill = (float**) malloc(channelCount * sizeof(float*));

for(int i = 0; i < channelCount; ++i)
{
    arrayToFill[i] = (float*) malloc(frameCount * sizeof(float));
}
```

or, if the number of channels is known ahead and fixed:

```
#define CHANNEL_COUNT 2

float *arrayToFill[CHANNEL_COUNT];

for(int i = 0; i < CHANNEL_COUNT; ++i)
{
    arrayToFill[i] = (float*) malloc(frameCount * sizeof(float));
}
```

Comment: The unnecessary and dangerous casts of malloc should be removed. (See the comments under the question.) It's also safer and more general to use `sizeof *arrayFill` and `sizeof *arrayFill[i]` rather than to explicitly name the type. (Even more safe and general is to have an array allocation macro that takes an lvalue and a length, but a lot of people have an irrational opposition to C macros.)

Comment: The casts are unnecessary here, this is true. At the same time there is nothing specifically dangerous in them here. For certain extent then make the code clearer.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: It doesn't "make the code clearer", it clutters it with redundant characters.  Anyone who knows C knows it is wrong and redundant.  It can also hide the fact that you forgot to include `stdlib.h`, in which case `malloc` will be assumed to be a function which returns int.  The cast hides the error.  Given, this applies to compilers which only implement C89 (or older) versions, but unfortunately some popular compilers have not made the switch (VS anyone?)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you only need a rectangular array, you can just write

```
float* arrayToFill = malloc( channelCount * frameCount * sizeof(float) );
```

and access the different sections with just a little math

```
arrayToFill[ x + y * channelCount ];
```

If you absolutely must have the double subscript, or one of the dimensions is variable, there's no way out of doing what you already have.